# Can I put a horizontal line in a combo box or list control?

Tags: winforms

I'm building a Windows Form that includes a combo box control, and I wanted to put a horizontal line between certain items.  I've seen this done in other contexts using a hyphen in an item list, but a hyphen doesn't do this in this case. I don't know if a horizontal line is even possible with this control.  What I am trying to accomplish is something like:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
_________________
Item A
```

I suppose I could simply put a line of hyphens in there, but a nice clean line would be better if it could be done.

Comment: I hope this help, it sill needs improvement though. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092613/putting-horizontal-line-in-a-combo-box-or-list-control-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything that comes standard in the control with "clean" solutions yet.

I found something where you can draw the line between every item at this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/280066f8-f0e0-4708-ac67-969885b19aad).  With some fancy work you may be able to find a way of making it draw the line only when you want to.

Alternatively, there is a [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/SeparatorComboListBox.aspx) combobox that includes line separators.