# putting horizontal line in a combo box or list control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Answering the link: ([Can I put a horizontal line in a combo box or list control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017543/can-i-put-a-horizontal-line-in-a-combo-box-or-list-control))

I've create a code in C# (VS 2010) Windows Forms but it needs improvement. The symbol "-" in front of the item renders a line after the item.

My inputs in the combo item collections are as follow:

```
-All Names
Henry (Father)
-Nancy (Mother)
Sapphire
Vincent
```

My combo display like so:

```
All Names
------------------
Henry (Father)
Nancy (Mother)
------------------
Sapphire
Vincent
```

While my codes are:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        comboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cmb_Type_DrawItem);
    }

    void cmb_Type_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        string a = comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
        if (comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString().Substring(0, 1) == "-")
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1),
            new Point(e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1));
            a = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        }            
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, a,
        comboBox1.Font, e.Bounds, comboBox1.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

The improvement I need is in the "cmb_Type_DrawItem" i wanted the "comboBox1" to be parametrized so when i call it can be applied to any comboBox that called it (not just comboBox1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Martin's solution plus a public variable.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AttachHandler(comboBox1);
        AttachHandler(comboBox2);
        AttachHandler(comboBox3);
        AttachHandler(comboBox4);
        AttachHandler(comboBox5);
    }

    void AttachHandler(ComboBox combo)
    {
        combo.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        combo.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cmb_Type_DrawItem);
    }

    //using mycombo to make combobox variable
    void cmb_Type_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var mycombo = (ComboBox) sender;  // This is what I meant

        e.DrawBackground();
        string a = mycombo.Items[e.Index].ToString();
        if (mycombo.Items[e.Index].ToString().Substring(0, 1) == "-")
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1),
            new Point(e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1));
            a = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
        }
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, a, mycombo.Font, e.Bounds, mycombo.ForeColor, 
                     TextFormatFlags.Left);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: Why the public variable ? It does not add anything, but could create problems when there are multiple comboboxes on the form. The way this is implemented, if you have 2 combobox, the cmb_Type_DrawItem will always apply to the last combobox for which you have called AttachHandler.

Comment: how else can i express mycombo inside the cmb_Type_DrawItem if it's not editable, I do not want no make a new class just for that purpose. My problem is i can not pass a combo unless it goes to a variable combo so i use it for the DrawItem.

Comment: Also i will be just using only 1 combo variable even if there are plenty of combos in the form. See the AttachHandler mycombo = combo;

Comment: Ha, sorry, my bad, I had not spotted that part. However, since mycombo is only used in the cmb_Type_DrawItem method, you could simply define a variable inside of cmb_Type_DrawItem. In an eventhandler, the first parameter is the object which triggered the event. As such, at the start of the code in the eventhandler, you could do `var mycombo = (ComboBox) sender;` and remove the need for the field in your class and the assignment in AttachHandler

Comment: Doing as stated in my previous comment would lead to simpler and cleaner code.

Comment: this means can replace mycombo with sender? Example: string a = sender.Items[e.Index].ToString();

Comment: @Martin can you edit my answer to reflect that "var mycombo = (ComboBox) sender;"? I don't quite understand that part or how to apply it.

Comment: Ok. I have done it. Check the first line of cmb_Type_DrawItem. I also made the other changes I talked about in my other comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it as Blau suggested or create a function that will attach the event handler to combobox.

```
void AttachHandler(ComboBox combo) {
    combo.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    combo.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cmb_Type_DrawItem);
}
```

Then, in your form constructor, you simply use:

```
public Form1() {
    AttachHandler(comboBox1);
    AttachHandler(comboBox2);
}
```

Comment: What about the codes at "cmb_Type_DrawItem" in which i was asking about?

Comment: Since cmb_Type_DrawItem is an eventhandler, you can't change its signature.

Comment: I just realized, if you choose this solution, you will also have to change the code of your event handler because instead of referring to combobox1, you will have to use the current ComboBox by using var combo = (ComboBox) sender; and replace all your references to comboBox1 to combo.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own combobox:

```
  public class MyComboBox : ComboBox {

       override DrawItem() {
              ....
       }
  }
```